# Drop a column with same name using column index in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my dataframe I'm trying to drop the duplicate columns with same name using index:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4,5)],['c','b','a','a','b'])
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  c|  b|  a|  a|  b|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I got the index of the dataframe

```
col_dict = {x: col for x, col in enumerate(df.columns)}
col_dict
```

Output:

```
{0: 'c', 1: 'b', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'b'}
```

Now i need to drop that duplicate column name with the same name

Answer (score 7):

There is no method for droping columns using index. One way for achieving this is to rename the duplicate columns and then drop them.

Here is an example you can adapt:

```
df_cols = df.columns
# get index of the duplicate columns
duplicate_col_index = list(set([df_cols.index(c) for c in df_cols if df_cols.count(c) == 2]))

# rename by adding suffix '_duplicated'
for i in duplicate_col_index:
    df_cols[i] = df_cols[i] + '_duplicated'

# rename the column in DF
df = df.toDF(*df_cols)

# remove flagged columns
cols_to_remove = [c for c in df_cols if '_duplicated' in c]
df.drop(*cols_to_remove).show()

+---+---+---+
|  c|  a|  b|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+
```